# How to produce this kind of long table using overleaf?

Tags: tabularx

[image]

How to produce this kind of long table using overleaf?

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE :) // Please spend some effort to come up with and post some code. You may want to consult e.g. the wikibooks https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- You not provide any information about your document and if you really need long table, so rest of answer is based on guessing and can serve only as starting point.
- With `longtblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package `tabularray`, it is easy to set row heights.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {My First Long Table},
  label = {not:long},
  ]{hlines, vlines,
    colspec = {Q[c,h] X[2,l] Q[c,f] X[1,l]}, 
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries,c},
    row{2-Z} = {33mm},
    rowhead=1
    }
No. & Workflow  & ? &   Remarks     \\
1   &           & 4 &               \\
2   &           &   &               \\
3   &           &   &               \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Than you s very much